# How can override Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Attribute_Source_Mode in MAGENTO?

Tags: magento, model, attributes

How can override ATTRIBUTE SOURCE in CMS Magento ?
Tried standard method but not working.

> **I think that this unreal :(**

Answer (score 1):

In the config.xml file:

```
<models>
   <catalog>
       <rewrite>
           <category_attribute_source_mode>YOUR CLASS HERE</category_attribute_source_mode>
       </rewrite>
   </catalog>
</models>
```